# Issue playing audio with Stackoverflow's javasound tag example

Tags: java, audio

Reading about the [javasound](/questions/tagged/javasound) tag earlier today, I tried to implement the simple code that we can see there (with some minor modifications, such as using `File` instead of `URL`):

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/sound.wav");
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
clip.open(ais); // exception
```

But I'm getting a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format` when I try to open the `AudioInputStream` that we see there.

However, when I try it with the following code that I got from the internet

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/sound.wav");
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
AudioFormat format = ais.getFormat();
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
Clip clip = (Clip)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
clip.open(ais);
clip.start();
```

it **does** work: `sound.wav` is played correctly - however, I find this to be clunky for something that should be as simple as our first example, given on the [javasound](/questions/tagged/javasound) tag itself.

By reading the [documentation from clip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html), I acknowledged that `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown when `[...] the stream's audio format is not fully specified or invalid`. However, it does seem to be a valid format.

What is wrong with our first example here? [AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioFileFormat(java.io.File)) does accept a `File` as argument, and, as visible from the second example, it does appear to have valid audio file data, because it works. Am I missing something obvious? And, if so, shouldn't it be pointed out on [javasound](/questions/tagged/javasound) tag?

Comment: I use a similar simple code and it works, maybe .wav file has something wrong in it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211090/java-play-multiple-clips-simultaneously/23487878#23487878

Comment: That's funny, because I think that if, perhaps, it had something wrong with it, it probably wouldn't play with the second example. However, that cast might have something to do with it. I'll try to mess around a bit more with the file to see if I can see something odd.

Comment: Some additional info is that I recorded it myself, using [Audacity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audacity_(audio_editor)), and then exported it as a `wav` file.

Comment: Try running ffmpeg conversion if that fixes something. ffmpeg -i input.wav -vn -acodec pcm_s16le output.wav

Comment: Do `System.out.println(format);` and tell us what the format is.

Comment: @Radiodef it outputs `PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian`. I'll try to run ffmpeg as suggested by Whome to see if something happens

Comment: Unfortunately, Whome's tip of running ffmpeg didn't work out too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I found out that it could have something to do with the system properties. In those properties you can specify defaults for the getLine() methods (getLine(), getClip(), getSourceDataLine() and getTargetDataLine()). If you call one  of these methods, Java does the following ([AudioSystem description](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html)):

The system property javax.sound.sampled.Clip is set to

javax.sound.sampled.Clip = great.Mixer#great.clip.Clap

The Mixer class is called *great.Mixer* and the Clip is called *great.clip.Clap*

When you request a Clip, Java checks the following:

- If the Mixer *great.Mixer* is found and contains the Clip *great.clip.Clap*, return this Clip
- If the Mixer *great.Mixer* is found, but does not contain the Clip *great.clip.Clap*, return the first Clip specified in the Mixer
- If the Mixer *great.Mixer* does not contain any Clips or if it isn't found, return the first instance of *great.clip.Clap* in any Mixer
- If no Mixer contains *great.clip.Clap*, return the first Clip of the first Mixer found
- If no Clip is specified in any Mixer, throw an **IllegalArgumentException**

What that means is that if you are getting an IllegalArgumentException, no Clips are installed in any Mixers.

With

```
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
```

you are defining a new Clip. Which means your next Call to a getLine() method will return this object instead of giving you an error.

Comment: Whoa, I wasn't expecting to get any answer on this anymore. Thank you!