# Why does AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream() throw IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, audio, wav, illegalargumentexception

I am working on a game in Eclipse. I have some code that plays a wav file:

```
public void play(String path) {
    try {
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        URL soundURL = getClass().getResource(path);
        clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundURL));
        clip.play();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem is, even though I have a valid path (I have tested), I get an error that says:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format
```

Here's the full error message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format
at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.createStream(PulseAudioDataLine.java:142)
at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:99)
at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:283)
at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:402)
at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:453)
at tools.SoundTools.play(SoundTools.java:17)
at gamestate.MainState.mouseReleased(MainState.java:102)
at gamestate.GameStateManager.mouseReleased(GameStateManager.java:56)
at main.GamePanel.mouseReleased(GamePanel.java:118)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3311)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

I am very confused about this, I just want to play a sound! ;( If one of you could help me, I would be very appreciative!

Comment: What is the path you are passing to the method?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheElfHat The path is "/Sounds/coin.wav" but I know that is the correct path because `getClass().getResource(path)` returns a vaild URL and I got the sound to play with an extremely ugly heap of code.

Comment: I have narrowed down the problem to `clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundURL));` (the clip.open() part)

Answer (score 0):

Java is obviously complaining about a format, which is most likely the AudioFormat of your .wav file. The file is probably compressed in a way that is not implemented in java and therefore invalid. .wav files usually contain raw PCM data but they can also be compressed in various way.

Try changing the format of your .wav file into PCM using an audio converter/editor (Audacity)

List of supported formats:
 [JMF 2.1.1 - Supported Formats](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/formats-138492.html)

Comment: I found out something different. It may have something to do with the system.properties that Java checks when loading a Clip. See this thread for further information:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26435282/issue-playing-audio-with-stackoverflows-javasound-tag-example/29631885#29631885).