# Java - Clip won't play after re-opening

Tags: java, audio, clip

I'm using the javax.sound api to play audio clips and it works fine the first time, but after I close the clip, reopen it and try to play it again I get nothing. If I don't close it, it replays fine but I'd prefer closing all media once they're done playing. What do I need to change? What am I missing?

```
public class MediaClip {

protected boolean loop = false;
protected AudioInputStream audioStream;
protected Clip clip;
protected LineListener listener;

public MediaClip(AudioInputStream inAudioStream, boolean doesLoop) {
    audioStream = inAudioStream;
    loop = doesLoop;

    try {
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    listener = new LineListener() {

        @Override
        public void update(LineEvent event) {
            if (event.getType() != LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
                return;
            }

            if(clip == null) {
                return;
            }

            clip.close();
        }
    };
}

public void play() {
    boolean playing = clip.isRunning();
    if(playing == true) {
        return;
    }

    boolean lineOpen = clip.isOpen();
    if(lineOpen == false) {
        openLine();
    }

    clip.setFramePosition(0);
    clip.start();
}

private void openLine() {
    try {
        clip.open(audioStream);
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(loop == true) {
        clip.setLoopPoints(0, -1);
        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
    }

    clip.addLineListener(listener);
}
}
```

Comment: Either, after closing the `clip` make it `null` or set it's `framePosition` back to `0`...

Comment: Already tried setting the framePosition. Tried setting the clip to null and getting a new clip from the AudioSystem but didn't help. Still just plays once

Comment: Do this help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/23487878/185565 its an example of multiple clips and recurring playback.